# Running two methods from a class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have class A in which i have two methods defined ValidateA and ValidateB

```
class A {
   ValidateA() {
        /////
    }

   ValidateB() {
        ////
    }
}
```

I want to run both these steps in parallel at same time and get there combined status. How can i proceed using threads?

Comment: Reading this could be a start : http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait for all threads in an Executor to finish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787602/wait-for-all-threads-in-an-executor-to-finish)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always recommended to make use of the great `Executors` classes introduced in Java 5.  They help you manage your background tasks and hides the `Thread` code from your classes.

Something like the following would work.   It creates a thread-pool, submits 2 `Runnable` classes which each call one of the validate methods, and then waits for them to finish and return.  It uses a `Result` object that you will have to make up.  It could also be a `String` or `Integer` and depends on what the validate methods return.

```
// reate an open-ended thread pool
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// since you want results from the validate methods, we need a list of Futures
Future<Result> futures = new ArrayList<Result>();
futures.add(threadPool.submit(new Callable<Result>() {
    public Result call() {
       return a.ValidateA();
    } 
});
futures.add(threadPool.submit(new Callable<Result>() {
    public Result call() {
       return a.ValidateB();
    } 
});
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown,
// the already submitted jobs will continue to run
threadPool.shutdown();

// we wait for the jobs to finish so we can get the results
for (Future future : futures) {
    // this can throw an ExecutionException if the validate methods threw
    Result result = future.get();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For another more complex example using ExecutorService, see [this blog post](http://flyingspaniel.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-parallelize-your-algorithm-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

read about [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

```
class A {
  public Thread t1;
  public Thread t2;
  CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(3);
  public void validateA() {
    t1=new Thread(){
       public void run(){
         cb.await();       //will wait for 2 more things to get to barrier
          //your code
        }};
    t1.start();
  }
  public void validateB() {
    t2=new Thread(){
       public void run(){
         cb.await();      ////will wait for 1 more thing to get to barrier
          //your code
        }};
    t2.start();
  }
  public void startHere(){
        validateA();
        validateB();
        cb.wait();      //third thing to reach the barrier - barrier unlocks-thread are                 running simultaneously
  }
}
```

Comment: What's with the call to `Object#wait()` in `A#startHere()`? This design is bait for forcing a `NullPointerException` if the caller didn't realize that he needs to have called `ValidateA()` and `ValidateB()` before calling the enticingly-named `startHere()`.

Comment: sorry. fixed.. - running startHere will do all the work.